# Верстка сайта DIV'ами с шапкой, меню и полем для информации

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Мне нужно сверстать следующий сайт исключительно с помощью `<div>`.
Во внешний `<div>` погружены три `<div>`.
Первый `<div>` - `Шапка` тянется по ширине страницы и имеет фиксированный размер.
Под ним расположены `<div>` - `Меню` и `Информация`, высота которых должна изменяться в зависимости от размера окна браузера.

Был написан код HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Insert title here</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="NewFile.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='main-content'>
            <div id='header'>
                <h1>Шапка</h1>
            </div>
            <div id='menu'>
                <h1>Меню</h1>
            </div>
            <div id='info'>
                <h1>Информация</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
html,body {
    margin              : 0;
    padding             : 0;
    height              : 100%;
}
#main-content {
    border              : 5px ridge #8b7e96;
    position            : fixed;
    height              : 98%;
    width               : 99%;
    margin              : 2px;
}
#header {
    margin              : 2px;
    padding             : 2px;
    height              : 100px;
    background          : #FFEF97;
    border              : 5px ridge #8b7e96;
}
#menu {
    margin-left         : 2px;
    width               : 300px;
    height              : 85%;
    border              : 5px ridge #8b7e96;
    float               : left;
    background          : #FFC597;
}
#info {
    margin              : 2px 2px 2px 317px;
    border              : 5px ridge #8b7e96;
    padding             : 2px;
    height              : 84%;
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить следующие задачи:

1. Растянуть внутренние `<div>` с `Меню` и `Информация` по всей высоте внешнего `<div>` и при этом внутренние `<div>` имели бы один размер по высоте.
2. Сделать так, чтобы при уменьшении размеров окна браузера внутренние `<div>` `Меню` и `Информация` не выходили за границы внешнего `<div>`.

Comment: Похоже на тестовое задание...

Comment: Для дивов, которые должны тянуться - height: 100%; Мб и для родителя тоже надо будет задать высоту, в общем поиграйтесь с высотой.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую поизменять высоту дивов.

Answer (score 1):

Тут нужно:
1) закинуть все, что под шапкой, в отдельный контейнер, потом задать высоту внутренних - 100% Они и впишутся во внешний. Для отступов использовать padding этого общего контейнера, например.
2) с position поработать. float не нужен, раз там именно обтекания не предполагается. Сойдет relative для информационного блока с таким же отступом, как ширина меню, и absolute для самого меню. И целесообразность fixed для всего сайта крайне сомнительна. Для большинства случаев имеет фиксировать только шапку.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, начало проясняться